# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ether, web3-providers

i have contract which looks like following

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Rental {
    struct PaidRent {
        uint id;
        uint value;
    }
    PaidRent[] public paidrents;
    event RentPaid(bool Status);
    function payRent() public payable returns(bool status) {

        if(owner.send(msg.value)) {
          RentPaid(true);
          return true;
        } else {
          RentPaid(false);
          return false;
        }

    }
}
```

i am calling this function from my service using web3 in following way

```
paymyRent(contractInstance, rent) {
    console.log('in paymyrent');
    let eventlistenenr = contractInstance.RentPaid();
    eventlistenenr.watch(function (error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(result.args);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });


    contractInstance.payRent({from: this.web3.eth.accounts[0],
      gas:4665270, value: this.web3.toWei(rent, "ether")});
}
```

but upon sybmitting my transaction from metamask transaction is being failed. here is the screenshot of a transaction detail
[image]

any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: could you paste here the tx hash? And, are you sure it's the correct contract deployed? I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: @EliDrion here is the TxHash :0x730c634b581fcdad81ba53829a6611e9b598383572e78ff4332f15a6645afdca

Comment: yes. it is the correct contract deployed. when i call other functions of contract it is returning expected result

Comment: Hard to know. It works well.

Comment: thanks man. i deployed a new contract and it is working fine now. don't know what was wrong with previous contract.